# Jsp. Page validation...

Tags: jsp, servlets

On a jsp page  I Want to validate a file path for example I Wan to check that some server is present on that path which I have specified how to do that?     Can someone give code for that

Comment: `404` - Requested page does not exists. Does that sounds familiar ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just with this simple trick if you want to do it with AJAX and javascript.

```
function callstatus(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost:8088/ProjectName/restController",
        cache: false,
        success : function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        statusCode: {
            200 :function() {
                alert('200 status code! Success ');
            },
            400: function() {
                alert('400 status code! user error');
            },
            404: function() {
                alert('404 status code! user error');
            },
            500: function() {
              alert('500 status code! server error');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why is HTTP 200 OK "User Error"?

Comment: Little more clarification on your answer..... I Wan to also jsp that any input field I have file location that will be present there or not...